# Не выполняется цель из makefile

Tags: makefile

В makefile не запускается почему-то при запуске
qemu-system-x86_64 main.bin, а так всё работает без ошибок

```
main.bin:main.asm readDisk.asm printf.asm
        -       nasm -fbin main.asm -o main.bin
        -
clean:  -
        -       rm main.bin
        -
run:    -
        -       qemu-system-x86_64 main.bin
```

Подскажите пожалуйста где у меня ошибка, работаю в Ubuntu 16.04

вот какой у меня файл сейчас:

```
main.bin:main.asm readDisk.asm printf.asm
        nasm -fbin main.asm -o main.bin

clean:
        rm main.bin

run:    main.bin
        qemu-system-x86_64 main.bin
```

Сделал всё как вы просили отступы и удалил минусы

Answer (score 0):

программа *make*, если цель не указана явно при вызове (`$ make имя-цели`), выполняет первую упомянутую в *makefile* цель.

в вашем случае это `main.bin`.

если вы хотите выполнить цель `run`, то можете так и указать программе *make*:

```
$ make run
```

---

если вам надо, чтобы всегда по умолчанию выполнялась именно цель `run`, то либо переставьте её выше, либо добавьте «заглушку» в начало файла — одну лишь [цель, без пререквизитов и рецепта](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html#Rule-Syntax):

```
run:

main.bin: ...
...
clean:
...
run:
...
```

---

в любом случае, так как цель `run` имеет смысл выполнять только **после** создания файла `main.bin`, его-то и надо указать в качестве пререквизита для этой цели. т.е. вместо:

```
run:
    qemu-system-x86_64 main.bin
```

напишите, например, так:

```
run: main.bin
    qemu-system-x86_64 main.bin
```

---

и не забывайте, что отступы перед рецептом выполняются не пробелами, а символом табуляции.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: А вот не получается

Comment: А вот не получается тип ошибки такой "make: «main.bin» не требует обновления.
sergey@COMPUTER:~/Рабочий стол/myOS/src/boot$ " и даже со старым файлом я выбрал ваш второй вариант тот который run: main.bin

Comment: это не ошибка. это информационное сообщение. 1. дополните текст вопроса текущим содержимым файла. 2. уберите из файла те минусы, которые вы туда вставили. 3. отступы делайте одним символом табуляции, а не пробелами.

Comment: дополнил текст вопроса текущим содержимым файла

Comment: вот какая ошибка выскакивает при команде make: "make: «main.bin» не требует обновления. sergey@COMPUTER:~/Рабочий стол/myOS/src/boot$ ", но сначала я удалил из папки main.bin файл, но опять всё сработало кроме qemu

Comment: ну так вы же **не перенесли** цель `run`, сделав её самой первой. о чём я и написал целый ответ. вам что-то в нём осталось непонятным?

Comment: то есть если я правильно понимаю мне нужно только написать в заголовке файла run: и всё

Comment: да, как один из вариантов, можете в самом начале файла добавить строку, состоящую из четырёх симоволов: `run:`. как второй вариант, можете всю реализацию цели `run` перенести из конца файла, где она сейчас у вас находится, в начало: просто вырезать эти две строки и вставить самыми первыми в файл.

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Всё заработало большое вам спасибо

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Оставить как есть